# Find surface area using surface integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the area of surface of solid bounded by cone $z=3-(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and paraboloid $z=1+x^2+y^2$

---

I have not been able to figure out figure of the question. Please help me with this.i would be helpful if someone can upload hand written solution with neat diagrams . thanks in advance

Comment: Keep in mind that homework-type problems on this site are usually not well-received unless you show an attempt at a solution, or are asking for clarification on a certain aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we find the intersection curve of the two solids:

Let $t = (x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, then: $3-t = 1 + t^2$. Thus: $t^2 + t - 2 = 0$. So $(t-1)(t+2) = 0$, and $t = 1, -2$. Since $t > 0$, $t = 1$, or $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Let $S$ be the surface area of the solid bounded by the paraboloid and the cone, then:

$S = S_1 + S_2$, with:

$S_1$ = surface area of the cone, and $S_2$ = surface area of the paraboloid.

For the cone, $z_x^2 + z_y^2 + 1 = \dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{x^2+y^2} + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2$, and for the paraboloid we have: $z_x^2 + z_y^2 + 1 = 4(x^2+y^2) + 1$. Thus:

$S_1 = \displaystyle \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{r = 0}^1 \sqrt{2}rdrd\theta = \sqrt{2}$ $\left(\text{just the area of the unit circle times} \sqrt{2} \right)$.

$S_2 = \displaystyle \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{r = 0}^1 \sqrt{4r^2+1}rdrd\theta$.

Let $u = 4r^2 + 1$, then $du = 8rdr$. Thus: $S_2 = \displaystyle \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{u=1}^5 \dfrac{\sqrt{u}}{8}dud\theta = \dfrac{(5\sqrt{5} - 1)\pi}{6}$. Thus:

$S = S_1 + S_2 = \sqrt{2} + \dfrac{(5\sqrt{5} - 1)\pi}{6}$

Comment: hi thanks for the answer . but in my textbook it seems there is different answer.its pi/6(37multiplysquareroot37 - 1)                            .they have written hence total surface area of paraboloid bounded by cone is equal to double integral over x^+y^=9 and integrand is squareroot of 1+4x^2+4y^2